# Numpy - assign column data types (dtype) to existing array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a given array:

```
array = [(u'Andrew', -3, 3, 100.032) (u'Bob', -4, 4, 103.323) (u'Joe', -5, 5, 154.324)]
```

that is generated from another process (that I cannot control) of taking a CSV table and it outputs this numpy array.  I now need to assign the dtypes of the columns to do further analysis.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: what is this question -1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
new_array = np.array(array, dtype = [("name", object), 
                                     ("N1", int), 
                                     ("N2", int),
                                     ("N3", float)])
```

where name and N1-3 are column names I gave.

It gives :

```
array([(u'Andrew', -3, 3, 100.032), (u'Bob', -4, 4, 103.323),
       (u'Joe', -5, 5, 154.324)], 
      dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('N1', '<i8'), ('N2', '<i8'), ('N3', '<f8')])
```

You can sort on "N1" for instance :

```
new_array.sort(order="N1")
new_array
array([(u'Joe', -5, 5, 154.324), (u'Bob', -4, 4, 103.323),
       (u'Andrew', -3, 3, 100.032)], 
      dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('N1', '<i8'), ('N2', '<i8'), ('N3', '<f8')])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
recarr = np.rec.fromrecords(array)
```

Optionally set field names:

```
recarr = np.rec.fromrecords(array, names="name, idata, idata2, fdata")
```