# Why is it that the numpy array column data type does not get updated?

Tags: python, string, numpy, int, numpy-ndarray

```
nd2values[:,[1]]=nd2values[:,[1]].astype(int)
nd2values
```

outputs

```
array([['021fd159b55773fba8157e2090fe0fe2', '1',
        '881f83d2dee3f18c7d1751659406144e',
        '012059d397c0b7e5a30a5bb89c0b075e', 'A'],
       ['021fd159b55773fba8157e2090fe0fe2', '1',
        'cec898a1d355dbfbad8c760615fde1af',
        '012059d397c0b7e5a30a5bb89c0b075e', 'A'],
       ['021fd159b55773fba8157e2090fe0fe2', '1',
        'a99f44bbff39e352191a870e17f04537',
        '012059d397c0b7e5a30a5bb89c0b075e', 'A'],
       ...,
       ['fdeb2950c4d5209d449ebd2d6afac11e', '4',
        '4f4e47023263931e1445dc97f7dae941',
        '3cd0b15957ceb80f5125bef8bd1bbea7', 'A'],
       ['fdeb2950c4d5209d449ebd2d6afac11e', '4',
        '021dabc5d7a1404ec8ad34fe8ca4b5e3',
        '3cd0b15957ceb80f5125bef8bd1bbea7', 'A'],
       ['fdeb2950c4d5209d449ebd2d6afac11e', '4',
        'f79a2b5e6190ac3c534645e806f1b611',
        '3cd0b15957ceb80f5125bef8bd1bbea7', 'A']], dtype='<U32')
```

The data type of the second column is still `str`. Is it because this particular numpy array has `dtype` restriction? How would you change the second column to `int`? Thanks.

```
np.array(nd2values,dtype=[str,int,str,str,str])
```

gives

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy - assign column data types (dtype) to existing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864913/numpy-assign-column-data-types-dtype-to-existing-array)

Comment: `dtype` belongs to the whole array, not a column. You'd have to make a structured array with a compound `dtype` to get different dtypes for each `field`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignement is casting your ints to the type of the array. To be able to hold all kind of objects in an array set the dtype to object.

```
nd2values = nd2values.astype(object)
```

then

```
nd2values[:,[1]]=nd2values[:,[1]].astype(int)
```

Comment: Beware that math on that `object` dtype array is slower.  The array now contains pointers to objects elsewhere in memory, just like a `list`.

Answer (score 2):

A structured array alternative:

A copy-n-paste from the question gives me a (6,5) array with `U32` dtype:

```
In [96]: arr.shape
Out[96]: (6, 5)
```

define a compound dtype:

```
In [99]: dt = np.dtype([('f0','U32'),('f1',int),('f2','U32'),('f3','U32'),('f4','U1')])
```

Input to a structured array should be a list of tuples:

```
In [100]: arrS = np.array([tuple(x) for x in arr], dt)
In [101]: arrS
Out[101]: 
array([('021fd159b55773fba8157e2090fe0fe2', 1, '881f83d2dee3f18c7d1751659406144e', '012059d397c0b7e5a30a5bb89c0b075e', 'A'),
       ('021fd159b55773fba8157e2090fe0fe2', 1, 'cec898a1d355dbfbad8c760615fde1af', '012059d397c0b7e5a30a5bb89c0b075e', 'A'),
       ('021fd159b55773fba8157e2090fe0fe2', 1, 'a99f44bbff39e352191a870e17f04537', '012059d397c0b7e5a30a5bb89c0b075e', 'A'),
       ('fdeb2950c4d5209d449ebd2d6afac11e', 4, '4f4e47023263931e1445dc97f7dae941', '3cd0b15957ceb80f5125bef8bd1bbea7', 'A'),
       ('fdeb2950c4d5209d449ebd2d6afac11e', 4, '021dabc5d7a1404ec8ad34fe8ca4b5e3', '3cd0b15957ceb80f5125bef8bd1bbea7', 'A'),
       ('fdeb2950c4d5209d449ebd2d6afac11e', 4, 'f79a2b5e6190ac3c534645e806f1b611', '3cd0b15957ceb80f5125bef8bd1bbea7', 'A')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U32'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<U32'), ('f3', '<U32'), ('f4', '<U1')])
```

One field can be accessed by name:

```
In [102]: arrS['f1']
Out[102]: array([1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4])
```