# What is dtype with more than one element in ndarray of numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

```
 x = np.array([(1,2),(3,4)],dtype=[('a','<i4'),('b','<i4')])
```

Why do we use the dtype with more than one elements in ndarray and how is it useful? How do we interpret this?

Comment: Check out the documentation on [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html)

Comment: This kind of `dtype` is most useful when the field dtypes differ, for example, strings from a label column, integers and floats for others.  It comes up most often when loading `csv` files.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291797/why-is-it-that-the-numpy-array-column-data-type-does-not-get-updated is an example of someone wanting both strings and integers in the same array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should notice that this array would only have one dimension which is represented by the dtype

```
('a','<i4'),('b','<i4')
```

The way I like to think about this is that we are creating a dtype by concatenating other dtypes together. We treat each pair of tuples as a single element of our array, with individual specs for each element of each tuple.

In other words, the dtype really just signifies the structure of the elements.

To learn more, see [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html)

Comment: Also we should be careful with terminology: `concatenate` is the name of a NumPy function with a specific meaning. There's no *real* combination, I'm not even sure data is stored in a contiguous memory block here.

Comment: Oh I'm aware it's not being concatenated lol. That isn't the point however. I think I used it in a fairly common colloquial manner, so I don't think that is a problem. If I was referring to np.concatenate, I would have said that