# Adding 2d Numy array to 1d Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having a python list, and each element is a 2d Numpy array with size of `(20, 22)`. I need to convert the list to a numpy array but doing `np.array(my_list)` is literally eating the RAM, so does `np.asarray(my_list)`.

The list has around 7M samples, I was thinking instead of converting my list to a numpy array, let me start with a numpy array and keep appending another 2d numpy arrays.

I cant find a way of doing that using numpy, my aim is to start with something like that:

```
numpy_array = np.array([])

df_values = df.to_numpy() # faster than df.values
for x in df_values:
    if condition:
        start_point += 20
        end_point += 20
    features = df_values[start_point:end_point] # 20 rows, 22 columns
    np.append(numpy_array, features)
```

As you can see above, after each loop, the size of `numpy_array` should be changing to something like this:

```
first iteration: (1, 20, 22) 
second iteration: (2, 20, 22) 
third iteration: (3, 20, 22) 
N iteration: (N, 20, 22)
```

Update:

Here is my full code,

```
def get_X(df_values):
    x = [] #np.array([], dtype=np.object)
    y = [] # np.array([], dtype=int32)
    counter = 0
    start_point = 20
    previous_ticker = None
    index = 0
    time_1 = time.time()
    df_length = len(df_values)
    for row in tqdm(df_values):
        if 0 <= start_point < df_length:
            ticker = df_values[start_point][0]
            flag = row[30]
            if index == 0: previous_ticker = ticker
            if ticker != previous_ticker:
                counter += 20 
                start_point += 20
                previous_ticker = ticker
            features = df_values[counter:start_point]
            x.append(features)
            y.append(flag)
            # np.append(x, features)
            # np.append(y, flag)
            counter += 1
            start_point += 1
            index += 1
        else:
            break
    print("Time to finish the loop", time.time()-time_1)
    return x, y


x, y = get_X(df.to_numpy())
```

Comment: Isn't `features` always the same array?

Comment: @DaniMesejo It is being changed based on the ```start_point```, and ```end_point```

Comment: @DaniMesejo okay, I updated it just to clear this out, thanks for noticing this

Comment: Appending to an array is not amortized unlike a list. You will waste a lot more RAM this way. Your best bet is the first option.

Comment: Show a complete [mcve] with random numbers or something. Most of the statements you're making are borderline nonsense. Your data is already in memory, and you're not showing what actually "eats up your ram", or what "condition" is

Comment: @MadPhysicist check it now please

Comment: I don't want to see your full code. I want to see a [mcve] that I can paste and run to see my RAM eaten up. And another that displays the problem you're having when you try the append solution. Please construct a [mcve]. This is very important because most likely you will realize the solution to your issue half way through.

Comment: I think the RAM issue is that when you convert with np.array, you will have essentially another copy of the data in RAM (in addition to the original lists). You could make the data into a numpy array from the start maybe? So avoid the list altogether.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am sorry but this is not always achievable! I cant share with everyone a private dataset of 7M records, can I ?

Comment: `np.random.randint(10, size=(20, 20, 7000000))` seems quite achievable. You aren't asking about any feature besides size and shape here, so besides being off a bit in the dtype, this is quite functionally representative.

Comment: My point is that the M in MCVE is the most important part. Learning to construct a proper example is 90% of debugging

Comment: @MadPhysicist I do agree with you. However, even your solution would not work as I am having textual data that varies in length, It is kinda difficult to produce a minimal reproducible example in here. In addition to that, I believe anyone with experience in big data can notice what's wrong here running a code as it's more a RAM issues then something that's not working. I appreciate your welling to help

Comment: @samerhassan. I would like to see how you use `np.array` because what you are saying makes less sense than you think on the surface.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am not sure If I am getting you here, but what I was trying to do next is just this: ```x = np.array(x)``` which is crashing after booking 15GB RAMs. OR did you mean something else?

Comment: @samerhassan. I'm not sure how that's possible given that the data is already in a dataframe in memory. That's why a mcve is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays are so efficent because they have a fixed size and type. Hence, "appending" to an array is very slow and consuming, because a new array is created all the time. If you know beforehand how many samples you have (eg 7000000) the best way is:

```
N = 7000000
# Make complete array with NaN's
features = np.empty(size=(N, 20, 22), dtype=np.float64) * np.NaN
for whatever:
    ...
    features[counter:start_point] = ...
```

Should be the fastest and most memory efficiant way, when using a loop. However, this looks like some transformation of a dataframe into the 3D array, which might be much, much faster solved with pandas numerous features for transformation.

If you do not know the final size, err on the bigger size and copy it once to the smaller (correct) size.

Comment: I believe this is a nice trick. However, changing np.float64 to np.object plays a huge role here, is there a certain way of specifying the data type for each column, as I am having textual data in some columns ? maybe you have got something else in mind ?

Comment: I think this answers my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864913/numpy-assign-column-data-types-dtype-to-existing-array#answer-24866061)

Comment: I wrote the answer without knowledge of the large code - np.float64 was just a guess. If you are dealing with strings, you need np.object of course. But there is a reason, why it is called "Num"Py and not "Object"Py or "Str"Py. If you have mixed types, I would avoid NumPy arrays completely - lists are better for that.